# Removing the trailing '.' from my wordpress directory URI

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp

I recently developed my own wordpress theme. I'm having an issue with it not working correctly. The style.css sheet cannot be found, though they are in fact in there. My template is a child of the twentyseventeen template and both style sheets are coming up as missing in my client log, because for some reason it looks like there's a trailing '.' in the directory path that gets spit out at me.

[image]

It's part of the path on the server end for some reason? Even though it doesn't have the '.' in it's directory file name that I can see on the server end here. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Try using a relative path. Swap out '/style.css' with './style.css'

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to be the thing breaking the code, I opened the local server and the links there have the same trailing '.' and seem to compile fine. Will update if I resolve.

Comment: have you tried get_template_directory_uri() instead of stylesheet uri ? first echo the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and check what it is echoing

Comment: I did actually, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'
```

it seems you are missing **'.'** while concatenating

Comment: I had actually had this first, upon testing it doesn't seem to break the code locally either. I've changed the functions.php file many different times with different methods to en queue the stylesheets which all ended up working on the local server but not on the virtual server. -  Meaning I am aware of how to concat, but I seen a method someone did it without that dot, and part of my troubleshooting was to see if it effected the output which it did not visually get rid of it, nor fix or change the output in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be with the configuration of the server and not the code itself, going to re-instantiate my droplet and try other methods here.